# Spark Map Functionality

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I am testing map and flatmap functionality of Spark. I basically need to use Flatmap later to convert Rows of a Spark Dataframe into a different format.

I created a dummy data frame as below:

```
Test code to check Flatmap
In [16]:

d={"a":[1,2,3],"b":[1.1,2.3,32],"c":[0,1,1]}
df=pd.DataFrame(d)
​
sdf=sqlContext.createDataFrame(df) 
sdf.show(5)
+---+----+---+
|  a|   b|  c|
+---+----+---+
|  1| 1.1|  0|
|  2| 2.3|  1|
|  3|32.0|  1|
+---+----+---+
```

Then I wrote the following function to do some computation on each Row object of Spark. I want to print and check what is happening at each step.

```
In [24]:

#print [x.asDict() for x in tmp]
def ex_map(x):
    print x
    y = x.asDict()
    print y
    sum_k = sum([y[k] for k in y.keys()] )

    return (k,sum_k)
​
print sdf.map(ex_map).take(4)
​
[('b', 2.1), ('b', 5.3), ('b', 36.0)]
```

Like I want to print the first Row object which is being passed to the map function.

Then I want to print the dict of this row object.

However in the end result I don't get to see these two prints command result.

What is going wrong?

Comment: Are you using a cluster to run that? Or it is your local machine?

Comment: local machine!!